# Parity inversion and time reversal transformation in Lorentz group

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

I understand the Lorentz group have 4 connected components, one of them being the proper orthochronous group $SO(1,3)^{+}$, where its matrix elements have determinant +1 and the component at column $0$ and row $0$ is $\geq1$ (i.e. $\Lambda_0^0\geq1$). The other three components will be given by:

{$T(SO(1,3)^{+})$ , $P(SO(1,3)^{+})$, $T(P(SO(1,3)^{+}))$}
where $T$ is a linear transformation that changes the sign of $\Lambda_0^0$ of a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$, and $P$ is a linear transformation that changes the sign of the determinant of a lorentz transformation.
If we consider:

$$\Lambda_{P}=\begin{pmatrix}1&&&\\&-1&&\\&&-1&\\&&&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

$$\Lambda_{T}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&&&\\&1&&\\&&1&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
I thought $T$ and $P$ would be defined by:

$T(A) = \Lambda_TA$ for any $A$ in $SO(1,3)^{+}$

$P(A) = \Lambda_PA$      for any $A$ in $SO(1,3)^{+}$

I was trying to verify this was true but most authors seem to exclude stating them more explicitly. I found in Wikipedia that these transformations actually behave as an adjoint action $Ad_{\Lambda_P}$, you can check  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Space_inversion_and_time_reversal).
It seems they are defined by:

$T(A) = \Lambda_T^{-1}A\Lambda_T$,
$P(A) = \Lambda_P^{-1}A\Lambda_P$ , for any $A$ in $SO(1,3)^{+}$.

Is this true? If so, what is the intuition behind them having to be similarity transformations? why can't they just be a single matrix multiplication (from the left) with the given $\Lambda_T$ and $\Lambda_P$ as I thought?

I was looking for a more reputable source that stated P and T more explicitly, if you can give one I would appreciate it.

Comment: Who is A ? An element of the full Lorentz group, or a geometrical object subject to a full Lorentz group transformation? @Qmechanic addresses the second possibility.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that OP is essentially asking

> *How do a physical quantity $A$ transforms under the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $G=O(3,1)$, in particular wrt.  the discrete generators [$P$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28physics%29) and [$T$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry)?*

*Brief answer:* That depends on the physical quantity $A$, and which [$G$-representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group) it transforms under. To mention one simple example: A [pseudoscalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar) is a quantity that changes sign under $P$, while a true [scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28physics%29) does not.